# How to make the first row of an UITableView a header of a section?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have an `UITableView` with custom cells. I would like that the first row is always visible. As I have only once section, I thought of making a header but in this case I don't really know how to do it?

Is it possible to make a header from the first row with the same gesture recognizers, same dataSource behind the rows, briefly, have the header exactly like th row, just as if the row was pined to the top of the tableView?

Comment: How are you setting up your tableView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a header, or a separate view outside the table view. You can use the same gestures (generally, though not the delete) and data source.

If you want it all, you could use 2 table views- the first with one section and one row, the second with all the other data. It would be easiest if your data source was broken down in a similar way in the view controller.

In either case you can achieve what you want, but not by flicking a switch, you will need to add some logic and different views to make it happen.

Comment: I actually have a refresh control that is triggered when I pan down my table view. If I do it with a view + tableView or 2 tableViews, I need them to move together when I pull down whether the header or any other row. I thought of wrapping the 2 tableViews in another one but then I don't know how (or even if it's possible) to pass a tableView as a TableViewCell

Comment: Then you must use a header view

Comment: By using a header view, you mean having my first row as the headerView? Because then I get a `no index path for table cell being reused` error (I'm talking about it in a comment of Wezly's answer)

Comment: No, I mean use a real header view and create a version of your cell to use there

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make one static cell that is pinned to the top but in all other ways the same to the others, you could simply add one to your `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count + 1
}
```

Then when you display the cells, check for the row number and always set the first row to contain your static header content.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // Create or set static cell content.
    }
}
```

The other way is to create a custom section header and set it using `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        var view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: That's how I tried to do it but didn't work out. I create the cell using `let header = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as MyCell`, it works as long as the first cell is still being displayed (even if we don't see it, I changed the size of this row by 0) and then I get a `no index path for table cell being reused` error